# Apache rewriterule with regular expressions

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite multiple pages like this ...

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php?action=printpage;topic=12345.67
```

To this ...

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/topic,12345.67.html
```

I have unsuccessfully tried to use ...

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?action=printpage;topic=([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/topic,$1.$2.html [R=302]
```

Apache server and my other non-related rewrites work fine. Can anyone offer any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match against the query string in a RewriteRule, you need to use a RewriteCond and the **%** back reference:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=printpage;topic=([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/topic,%1.%2.html? [R=302]
```